# Replace from index of one character to the end of another

Tags: string, swift

I wish to replace a string starting from an index of one character to the end of another character. Example replace all characters from index of `(` to index of `)` in the string `Somesong here - Artist (radio edit)` or even if the string is  `Somesong here - Artist (radio edit) (another one)`. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

I've tried this but I dont think I'll work out, I not too sure how to remove substring starting at a range.

```
var a =  "Somesong here - Artist (radio edit)"
let range = a.rangeOfString("(")
let range2 = a.rangeOfString(")")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it like this to use the `-` range:

```
 var str = "Somesong here - Artist (radio edit)"
 if let range = str.rangeOfString("-") {
     // str = Somesong here
     str.removeRange(range.startIndex..<str.endIndex)
 }

// str = Somesong here - New Artist
str += "- New Artist"
```

If you want to use the `(` range instead:

```
var str = "Somesong here - Artist (radio edit)"
if let range = str.rangeOfString("(") {
// str = Somesong here - Artist 
    str.removeRange(range.startIndex..<str.endIndex)
}

// str = Somesong here - Artist (not a radio edit)
str += "(not a radio edit)"
```

You can ofcourse add the `str += ...` withing the `if let`.

Answer (score 0):

Use your two ranges to create a new range and call `replaceRange`:

```
var a =  "Somesong here - Artist (radio edit)"
let range = a.rangeOfString("(")
let range2 = a.rangeOfString(")")

a.replaceRange(range!.startIndex...range2!.startIndex, with: "(live version)")
print(a) // Somesong here - Artist (live version)
```